# Spotfire - Need to get the latest coverage code based on the cost center and period

Tags: spotfire

I am struggling to fix a formula where i need to get the coverage code such as (zone, global, local or cluster) of the respective cost center based on the period. In simple, i need to get the coverage code which is assigned to the respective cost center for the latest period. For example for the cost center IN0201001 the coverage code is Local and it has been changed to Zone during June month, from the latest period  such as June month, the coverage code should be fixed as Zone in the calculated columns. Could you any one help me on this?

Comment: A sample dataset would be helpful. Also please share some of the things you have tried.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I dont know how to fetch in the sample data set or screen shot to answer your question. could you please help me?

Comment: If your dataset is a text file, you can copy the first few rows and paste them in your question. If the data is sensitive, just make up fake rows changing any informaion that you can't share.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I have resolved the issue. May be useful for everyone.  Firstly i have created the calculated column for the max_period against each cost center (expression: max([Period_val]) over ([Cost_Center])  ), secondly I have created another calculated column using the max-period to get the coverage (expression : Last([Coverage]) OVER ([Cost_Center],[Max_Period_CC])) . Thanks for your help.